# MongoDB find() returns empty array

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a simple flask app that does CRUD operations. I have a python module where I defined all functions and they all work fine; I can create, read, update and delete. I added a retrieve method where I call find() and it does retrieve the cursor. The problem is I can't get it to populate the data, all I get is an empty array []. I looped through the cursor and I used loads and dumps from bson.json_util, but I get the same result. Here is what the class looks like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

class AnimalShelter(object):

    def __init__(self, username, password):

        # Access the MongoDB databases and collections.
        self.client = MongoClient('localhost', ####)
        self.db = self.client['project']
        self.username = username
        self.password = password


# Create
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            return self.db.collection.insert(data) 
        else:
            print("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")
            return False
            
# Read
...
# Update
...
# Delete
...


# Retrieve
    def retrieve(self, data, projection):
        if data is not None:
            return self.db.collection.find(data, projection)
        else:
            return False
```

In the test file, I have:

```
animals = AnimalShelter(username, password)
            try:
                dog = dumps(list(animals.retrieve({"animal_type": "Dog", "name": "Flow"}, {"_id": False})))
                print(dog)

            except:
                print("Unable to find the outcome")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You made a mistake in the fields or values when inserting the data or when constructing the query.

Comment: I can retrieve the data from mongo shell with no issues. I verified that the data is there. If I  don't use dumps, I get the cursor object as: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7fd80becd9b0>

Comment: Your question doesn't show this.

Comment: I meant that when I mentioned that it retrieves the cursor. Still trying to figure out what's going on.